# auto as type template parameter in concept requirement clause

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
concept Rebindable = requires {typename T::template rebind<auto>;};

template<typename T>
struct rebindable
{
    template<typename U>
    using rebind = rebindable<U>;
};

template<typename T>
struct non_rebindable
{};
```

this code compiles fine on gcc and works as expected (`Rebindable<rebindable</*a type*/>>` is true, `Rebindable<non_rebindable</*a type*/>>` is false), however clang triggers `'auto' not allowed in template argument`. I was wondering, is auto as template argument an (intentional or non-intentional) extension on gcc or a new feature that hasn't been implemented yet by clang?

Comment: Are you compiling it in Clang with C++20 enbled and Concepts enabled? I know that concepts are avaible in clang 10 but everything hasn't been covered yet

Comment: Yes, i tested both on godbolt -> [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/b-kTRt) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/AAe_ka)

Comment: Looks like concepts are not fully covered by clang [clang concepts status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Comment: @ElGusanito that's what I'm asking, is it a feature not yet implemented by clang or a gcc extension (or a bug)?

Comment: No this is not standard, that is an extension of GCC